# Trying to force push, but Git is saying 'Everything is up to date'

Tags: git, github

**Issue:**

I have a master branch, dev branch, and a feature branch. Back then, I created a branch named **'checkout'** accidentally, I realized it later after I pushed it  and didn't bother to change it.

As time goes by, I kept merging to the development branch with new feature branches. Until yesterday ,I created a new branch named 'checkout'because I had a 'checkout page to pay for your items'. I forgot I already have a branch named 'checkout', so I decided to create a new branch named checkout (which brings checkout to HEAD), made a commit on it and pushed it to my remote repo.

I want to revert back to where I never created my new 'checkout branch'. This would be my latest development commit.

Here's my development branch.
https://github.com/mattfrancis888/project_2/commits/development

**My attempt in solving it:**

I tried to solve the issue with git reflog to rollback to the last development commit, which is one commit less than the remote repo. But now I can't seem to force push it. When I do `git push origin --all --force`. **Git says everything is up to date**. I can't 'revert' my remote repo to the rollbacked local repo now.

My HEAD seems to be on top eveyrthing. Here's what my local branch looks like now.

[image]

`git status` says that there's nothing to add. So I'm good there. Any ideas what's up?

Comment: (On a sidenote) You seriously created a branch named "checkout"? Even if it's technically possible since git does not prevent you from doing it, this is a *terrible* idea.

Comment: Yeah haha, I realized that afterwards and didn't bother change it.  But I promise you I will haha. I plan to figure out how to rename my remote branch after this

Comment: Also, where *is* this `checkout` branch? I can't see it in your graph. Wait.... is it a confusion with `sign_in`?

Comment: No!  'checkout' is not 'sign in'.  I created a checkout branch a long time ago accidently. Then recently, I created another one because I had a 'checkout' page. I made a commit on 'checkout' and realized that ain't good. The picture is what happened after I rollbacked and removed the recent 'checkout' branch!

Comment: You couldn't create another one. If the name already exists in your refs, depending on the method you used, it's either overwritten or denied, but you have only one branch afterwards, not two. What are you trying to fix here? All your branches are fine. The unwanted commit is nowhere to be seen. Does the `checkout` branch bother you? Delete it.

Comment: I think it over rides it. Because the # of commits changed in my checkout branch in github:https://github.com/mattfrancis888/project_2/branches. It went from 3 to 24 commits. My intention is to have two seperate branches. My old checkout and my new checkout. I would name the new checkout 'shopping_cart' . I want to do this just so my history looks cleaner and I can see what features I worked on.

Comment: 1. Back everything up to make it easier on yourself if you mess up. Especially since you're doing `--force`s... 2. Make sure you're on the correct branch. 3. Make sure you're pushing to the correct remote. 4. Don't use the `--force`, Luke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your branches are synced with their remote counterparts, there's nothing to push here, let alone to *force* push.

If you have commited on a `checkout` branch and don't want to keep it (nor the commit you made on it), just delete it with

```
git branch -D checkout
```

**Edit after comments** : ok, that's not it, let's sum up.

You had a `checkout` branch (rather old) which have recently been mistakenly updated both locally and on remote with a new branch which should be renamed `shopping-cart`.

You should search for the commits these branches pointed to before the confusion, reset them (with `git branch -f <branchName> <commitHash>`), then force-push them to the remote.

(From what you described so far, I assumed you were working alone on the repo of course...)

Comment: I don't think it's in sync because I rolled back my local repo to 1 commit less than the remote repo. Soo theoretically, can't I push --force my local repo since it's different than the remote one by 1 commit? Also! thanks for putting in the effort for trying to help out :)

Comment: OK ^^ So the whole diagram is rather pointless, if I may. The output of `git branch -vv` would be better (with a focus on the checkout branch, no need for the whole lot).

Comment: In my local repo, I already rolledback and deleted the new checkout branch. But here's what it looks like on development now. https://gyazo.com/5c564a72a008370cb0230e976aa2966c

Comment: Instead of 'git branch -f' I did git reflog and git reset --HARD HEAD@{x} to the commit before all the confusion occured. Which is the top most commit in the picture! So..wouldn't it have the same effect?

Comment: OK, I understand now why you didn't have it in the ouput, it's locally gone. Oh boy... So you'll have to check the reflog again, note the hash you want, and recreate the branch out of the commit hash with `git checkout -b <newBranchName> <commitHash>`

Comment: Okay! I did so, now do I just push and the new 'checkout' branch would be over-written?

Comment: Ahh, I solved it! I just pushed it and deleted my remote branch! thank you!!